# Laravel attach and sync issue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a small school management app with Laravel.

I have a many to many relationship between my table Courses and my table Disciplines (a course can have many disciplines).

Using Select2 JS, I can easily select my disciplines in my create blade view, but when I select one or many disciplines, different ones are shown in my show blade page.

Heres an example :

If I choose "Matière 3 and Matière 4", it shows me Matière 1 and Matière 2 in my index page.

[image]

[image]

If I choose Matie 1 (with Id 1) I get this error :

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`elearning`.`course_discipline`, CONSTRAINT `course_discipline_discipline_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`discipline_id`) REFERENCES `disciplines` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `course_discipline` (`course_id`, `discipline_id`) values (9, 0), (9, 1))

Here's my controller

```
public function createCourse(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'slug' => 'required|string',
        'status' => 'required|integer',
        'formation_id' => 'required|integer',
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'video_prev' => 'required',

    ]);

    $course = new Course();
    $course->title = $request['title'];
    $course->slug = $request['slug'];
    $course->status = $request['status'];
    $course->formation_id = $request['formation_id'];
    $course->description = $request['description'];
    $course->price = $request['price'];
    $course->video_prev = $request['video_prev'];
    $course->user_id = Auth::id();


    $course->save();

    $course->disciplines()->attach(request('disciplines'));

    return redirect(route('adminCourses'))->with('success', 'Le cours a bien été crée');

}

public function editCourse($id)
{
    $course = Course::findOrFail($id);
    $disciplines = Discipline::all();
    $formations = Formation::all();


    return view('admin.cours.editCourse', compact('course',  'disciplines', 'formations'));
}

public function editCoursePost(Request $request, $id)
{

    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'slug' => 'required|string',
        'status' => 'required|string',
        'formation_id' => 'required|string',
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'video_prev' => 'required',

    ]);

    $course = Course::findOrFail($id);

    $course->title = $request['title'];
    $course->slug = $request['slug'];
    $course->status = $request['status'];
    $course->formation_id = $request['formation_id'];
    $course->description = $request['description'];
    $course->video_prev = $request['video_prev'];
    $course->price = $request['price'];


    $course->save();

    $course->disciplines()->sync($request->input('disciplines', []));


    return redirect(route('adminCourses'))->with('success', "Le cours a bien été mis à jour");
}
```

My HTML Code for creating, updating and index :

Create :

```
<div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <label class="control-label">Matières</label>
                                        <select name="disciplines[]"  class="select2 form-control select2-multiple" multiple="multiple" >
                                            @foreach($disciplines as $id => $discipline)
                                                <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ in_array($id, old('disciplines', [])) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $discipline->title }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Update :

```
<div class="form-group row"
                                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                                        <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Matières</label>
                                        <select name="disciplines[]"  class="select2 form-control @error('disciplines') is-invalid @enderror" type="text select2-multiple" multiple="multiple"
                                            data-placeholder="Choisir une formation ..." required>
                                            @foreach($disciplines as $id => $discipline)
                                                <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ (in_array($id, old('disciplines', [])) || $course->disciplines->contains($id)) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $discipline->title }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Index :

```
<td>
                                            @foreach ($course->disciplines as $discipline)
                                                <span class="badge badge-danger">{{ $discipline->title }}</span> <br>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </td>
```

So now, I'm stuck...

Thank you everyone and stay safe !

Comment: Which exact line of your code shown here, does it fail on?

Comment: Hi mrhn. Thatś the problem... I don't know where the issue is. Thanks

Comment: In your log it will tell you where it fails